# Webserver on linux times out outside local network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jira

Apologies ahead of time if I mess up any terminology here; I am new to this realm.

I have setup Jira (bug tracking software) on a linux box in my local network.  I have a subdomain (jira.rairsoft.com) pointed to the box and apache/tomcat configured with redirect. All of this finally (after two weeks of headaches) works swimmingly.  But if colleagues outside the local network attempt to access it the response is that the webpage took too long to respond.  Pinging the subdomain has the same result (Request timed out).

My gut says that the port the service runs on is closed, but following steps I have found [elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193763%20elsewhere) to open the port have been fruitless.  I have also tried a packet sniffer on the port, accessed it, and didn't see anything at all "fly by", even if I access it inside the network.

Long story short, if I can access my Jira instance via subdomain inside the local network it is setup on then what do I need to do to expose it to the public?

Comment: Well, you'll need some sort of routing and probably NAT translation so that traffic from the outside world can get to your server. What did you mean by "apache/tomcat configured with redirect"? Redirect to where?

Comment: The subdomain gets redirected (maybe there's a better word to use?) to a port where the Jira application is running.

So in my mind it goes subdomain->IP->apache/tomcat->port->Jira.

Comment: Redirect or forwarded?

Comment: Sorry. Forwarded does sound more correct.

I followed the steps detailed [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Apache) if that helps with the things I can't explain very well.

Comment: @Bandrami You got me pointed in the right direction. I hadn't done any work on my router at all. If you add your comment in as an answer I'll mark it as such.